# What is the best way to structure a long-term python project that requires lots of arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

I have a number of python modules with different functionality which I want to run on their own or as part of a larger data pipeline. I've organised the code to do this with the following rough layout:

```
dataProcessing.py
import...
def main():....
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args = parser.parse_args([])
    parser.add_argument("--arg1").....
```

```
dataPipeline.py
import dataProcessing
def main():
    dataProcessing(args)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args = parser.parse_args([])
    parser.add_argument("--arg1").....
```

In this way I can arrange the modules in a pipeline and run them separately which is necessary for the project. However this does mean that the arguments need to be defined in both modules, which I can live with. This is okay for command line arguments, but harder when I come back to the files sometime later. Is there some way to have a file with the arguments already defined in so I it's easy to come back to the file and easier to edit rather than in the command line? I think a config file would be suitable but I am a bit doubtful about my general approach so any advice on best practice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use a config file.  Pick your format, but TOML is easy to write.  Then add an argument to the CLI that reads the args from the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just define a new `.py` file, where you define your arguments/parameters.
For instance, create a file `params.py`
and inside this file you would define a variable like:

```
var = 'sample_string.txt'
```

In your other python files you would `import`, for instance like that:

```
import params as p
```

and then you can use the arguments as such:

```
samplefilename_from_params_file = p.var
```

This allows you to have all arguments condensed in one file.
However, there are other methods to deal with that and have a real `configuration file`. That could be a `INI` file or a `yaml` file.